# Pyramid: serving a cached version on HTTP redirect

Tags: caching, cookies, nginx, pyramid

**I have the following URLs:**

- domain.com/ <== Returns a HTTPFound (302) to domain.com/todays_news
- domain.com/todays_news
- domain.com/tomorrows_news

What I would like is when someone visits domain.com/ and gets redirected to domain.com/todays_news, to get the cached version of the page,

but when they are on my website, and they click a link to domain.com/todays_news, they should get a fresh version of the page which will allow them to set cookies.

**The reason I want this behavior is because:**

- When they visit domain.com/todays_news directly I save a cookie
- If they visit the root url (domain.com/) I am NOT saving a cookie

**My Setup Looks like the following**

- Pyramid App running on uWSGI
- Nginx running with uWSGI pass (https://leons.im/posts/pyramid-nginx-uwsgi-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

How about this

- At the beginning of your `today_news()` Pyramid view check if `request.referrer` is `domain.com` - this should indicate redirect from this URL
- If it is set to `domain.com` query your cache (Redis, memcached) for cached page content and return this HTML
- If cached version is expired or referrer is different...
- Render page in your your Pyramid's `today_news()` view to HTML string
- Check if cache has expired and store the new version in cache (Redis, Memcached)
- Return HTML to the visitor, save cookies, etc. other HTML response manipulation

Comment: Thank you for the good idea, perhaps I did not explain it too well. I don't think that would be possible, Nginx is the one who is doing the automatic caching and rendering, it doesn't even touch my view if it has already cached a URL.

Comment: Surely it is possible. Just configure your Nginx not to cache `/today_news` and cache it internally in Pyramid.

Comment: In this manner it is possible, but I was trying to setup Nginx to do the caching to avoid the delay in making a request to Uwsgi, anyways thank you for the help

Comment: Pyramid + uWSGI is very efficient serving HTTP requests, so any delays in part of stack should be negligible unless you touch database on every request

Comment: You could try your luck with Nginx and lua scripting, but it would increase the programming complexity of your stack quite a bit and I don't see if it's worth of efficient gains doing it Nginx in-process